# How to get the list of suggested jenkins plugins via api or cli from jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm automating the jenkins installation along with plugin installation.As part of that i want to get the suggested plugins from jenkins server itself or install the same via api or cli instead of passing a list of plugins manually

Example: I want to get the below page plugins in a file or want to install the same via rest api or cli

Is it possible?

Note:

As of now,i'm pulled some important plugin names from websites/github accounts and just passing the plugin names manually by keeping them in a file.

[image]